# UltraChart DataBinding Problems

Tags: c#, dataset, infragistics, netadvantage

Ok so i currently have a handmade dataset database with 5 tables, all relationally linked and update whenever anything is done and it all works fine, but i also have an infragistice net advantages ultrachart, it is bound to one of my tables called Products, currently the graph shows 5 bars for EACH row in the table, one for the id one for the quantity sold, and 3 for various foreign keys, it does this because its just picked the columns from the table that are  of type integer, however i only want to show the Quantity sold bar for each row and use the ID as perhaps a key in the legend.

E.g ID 1 = blue bar, ID 2 = red bar, then on the chart show just the quantity sold, with its colour changing to reflect the id it is with. Anyone know how to do this?

if it helps the id is stored in column 0 and the quantity sold is stored in column 5, columns 1 2 3 and 4 i dont want to be considered for the graph.

Ive tried this for a good hour and i can't figure out how to do it! any help appreciated

Edit: note that i tried binding it to just the 5th column, this doesnt work the chart just shows up as a big red X across a white background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include/exclude specific column with:

```
myChart.Data.IncludeColumn(1, false);
```

or, if you have the DataTable available

```
myChart.Data.IncludeColumn(myDataTable.Columns["ColName1"], false);
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, cheers steve, though if you know how to add a legend, /key and how to colour code the bars according to the key that would be amazing!